# Using searchcursor and updatecursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm am trying to use a searchcursor to identify a list of ID's from a dataset. Using the list, I am now trying to delete those rows with the same ID's in another dataset.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
rtc_id_values = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(rtc_shp, "ID") as scursor:
    for srow in scursor:
        rtc_id_values.append(srow)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(corporate_rtc_dataset, "ID") as ucursor:
    for urow in ucursor:
        if urow in rtc_id_values:
            row.deleteRow()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've forgotten the indexes:

```
rtc_id_values.append(srow[0])

...

if urow[0] in rtc_id_values:
```

Currently you're using entire row objects, not field values.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the efficiency of your code with a list comprehension:

```
rtc_id_values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(rtc_shp, "ID")]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(corporate_rtc_dataset, "ID") as ucursor:
    for urow in ucursor:
        if urow[0] in rtc_id_values:
            row.deleteRow()
```